# Странная проблема с кодировкой при запуске python-скрипта UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, nohup

print() должна выводить русский текст, но вместо этого я получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    print('\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435\u043c \u0432\u0441\u0435 \u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440\u044b \u0434\u043b\u044f: ', key, cat_url, '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Скрипт запускаю на сервере, командой:

```
nohup python3 main.py &
```

**И самое странное:** Почему-то, когда я подключаюсь по SSH к серверу через мой другой компьютер и ввожу эту команду, то никакой ошибки нет. Может ли быть такое, что эта ошибка зависит например от программы, через которую я подключаюсь? В моем случае ошибка воспроизводится при подключении через PuTTy на Windows, но не воспроизводится при подключении через обычный терминал и ssh на macOS.

```
Сервер: ubuntu 18
Версия пайтон: 3.5.4
ОС на которой ошибка воспроизводится: Windows 7
ОС на которой ошибки нет: macOS
```

Comment: Выставите в настройках Translate у Pytty utf-8

Comment: Пропишите колировку в скрипте явно